# Is there a difference calling daemon(0,0) from within a program, and launching a program to be in background and redirecting it's output

Tags: c, linux

Is there a difference between having the following code at the begining of program 'progX'

```
if(daemon(0, 0) == -1)
{
    printf("daemon error: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

or running 'progX' via the command: progX & 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null 0>/dev/null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`daemon()` does several things:

- Re-parents the process to `init` by forking and then exiting the parent. Look in the `ps` list and you'll see that daemons are owned by PID 1.
- Calls `setsid()`.
- Changes directory to `/`.
- Redirects standard in, out, and error to `/dev/null`.

Your redirections handle the last action but not the rest.

Comment: and setsid() and so on....  I'm assuming the OP took care of everything in the daemon() call.  A good reference is Steven's 'Adavanced programming in the UNIX Environment' whole chapter on daemons.

Comment: hi all,
can any one tell me  where daemon() system call is defined ?

Comment: It's not a system call, it's a library call(that does several system calls) - it lives in glibc.

Comment: are stdin stdout and stderr are separate fot each process , if they are standard why to discard the data ?

Answer (score 1):

```
progX & 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null 0>/dev/null
```

stdin (0) is an input. Not output.  Daemon startup should close 0,1,2 - actually all open file descriptors right after it forks off from the parent process.  So I don't understand why you want to redirect error messages from daemon startup into /dev/null.

What that does is block any messages you might get from ProgX.  Just running ProgX as you wrote it is a better idea.

```
fprintf(stderr, "daemon error %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

might be better - errors go to stderr, printf outputs to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

daemon chdirs to /
daemon closes all fds

so you would need to

```
cd /
progX ....
```

for it to be the same