# Difference among background , agent and daemon app on osx/ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, launchd

what is the main difference among Backgroung app, agent and daemon on osx/ios.

As i know the following step to prepare it.
background app is making by changing info.plist as: `application is background only` to `YES`

agent app is making by changing info.plist as: `application is agent` to `YES`

and daemon is done by using `launchd`

can any one tell me what is the **main difference and purpose** of all three.

Comment: have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/DesigningDaemons.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference calling daemon(0,0) from within a program, and launching a program to be in background and redirecting it's output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966886/is-there-a-difference-calling-daemon0-0-from-within-a-program-and-launching-a)